# Como llamo a un archivo php desde html

Tags: php, html, css

Quisiera saber como puedo llamar a un archivo .php desde html sin usar el action="", Quiero saber si se puede hacer eso o necesariamente deberia crear un index.php y llamar con include("name_file").

Comment: Explica mejor que debes hacer y el resultado esperado pues en función de eso será la respuesta, que tiene el archivo deseado?

Comment: Pues llamar a un archivo .php desde html y que se ejecute todo lo que escriba ahi sin hacer click en el boton submit del formulario. Por eso decia que no sea de la forma action. Porque quiero que se ejecute el codigo que escriba en el php por ejemplo un echo sin tener que hacer click en el boton submit como te decia. Se puede hacer eso.?

Comment: Ejemplo, una búsqueda? que escribas algo y te traiga los resultados? si es así necesitas javascript

Comment: Para ejecutar un script php desde html debes, primero, llamarlo desde un archivo con extensión .php (si usas .html se mostrará el código php, no se ejecutará). Luego, en el lugar donde desees que se ejecute tu archivo php haces:   <?php include 'mi_archivo.php'; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Deberías explicar qué deseas realizar.
En el caso de utilizar un formulario la forma de invocar un archivo ***PHP*** es con:`<form action="archivo.php?>`
Otra forma podría ser a través de un link utilizando:`<a href="archivo.php">`.
Pero todo depende de qué es lo que deseas realizar o conseguir.